# Error: nodebuffer is not supported by this platform

Tags: shapefile, leaflet, react, leaflet-plugins

I'm trying to use Shpjs package for import Shape file on leaflet map bases on the shpjs doc : [shpjs](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/shapefile-js)

```
  const [geoData, setGeoData] = useState(null);
  const onChangeFile = ({ target }) => {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  var file = target.files[0];
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  reader.onload = function (buffer) {
  setGeoData(buffer.target.result);
  };
};
```

and after that i use shpjs package like this :

```
const geoJson =  await shp(geoData)
```

after import shp.zip i get this error :

[image: Error]

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56583916/why-jszip-cant-create-blob-file or this https://github.com/Stuk/jszip/issues/821 or this https://www.appsloveworld.com/reactjs/200/507/nodebuffer-is-not-supported-by-this-platform can help you going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Webpack? I just spent several hours troubleshooting this issue in a Quasar 2 app, using Webpack 5. As per their documentation... https://quasar.dev/start/upgrade-guide#nodejs-polyfills

> Webpack v5 removed the Nodejs polyfills for the web client builds. If you are using packages for the web client that rely on Nodejs API (they shouldn’t!), you will get errors saying that some packages are missing. Examples: Buffer, crypto, os, path.

So the solution for me was to just add nodePolyfillWebpackPlugin to my quasar.config.js chainWebpack method.

One more thing. I already had an eslint plugin in there, so digging in the webpack-chain api, this is how you specify multiple plugins:

```
const nodePolyfillWebpackPlugin = require('node-polyfill-webpack-plugin');
    chain.plugin('node-polyfill')
      .use(nodePolyfillWebpackPlugin)
      .end()
      .plugin('eslint-webpack-plugin')
      .use(ESLintPlugin, [{
        extensions: ['js', 'vue'],
        exclude: 'node_modules'
      }]);
```

note the ".end()" separating the two ".plugin()" calls.